# LINQ query with a WHERE clause with multiple conditions

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I use EntityFramework with POCOs.
Suppose I have POCOs defined like this (simplified):

```
class Class1
{
    public int ID;
    public int SomeNumber;
}

class Class2
{
    public int ID;
    public int SomeNumber;
}

class Class3
{
    public int ID;
    public int SomeNumber;
}

class SomeClass
{
    public int ID;
    public int? Class1ID;
    public Class1 Class1;
    public int? Class2ID;
    public Class2 Class2;
    public int? Class3ID;
    public Class3 Class3;
}
```

I want to fetch all `SomeClass` records from the database, that belong to an either one of `Class1`, `Class2` or `Class3` where `ClassX.SomeNumber` equals some number.

I wrote the LINQ query which looks like this:

```
Database DB = new Database(); // object context
var result = DB.SomeClass.ToList();

int SomeNumber = 1; // some number
List<SomeClass> retValue = result
    .Where(x =>
        {
            int Number = 0;
            if (x.Class1 != null)
                Number = x.Class1.SomeNumber;
            else if (x.Class2 != null)
                Number = x.Class2.SomeNumber;
            else if (x.Class3 != null)
                Number = x.Class3.SomeNumber;
            return Number == SomeNumber;
        })
    .ToList();
```

...however `retValue` doesn't contain any record.

**The solution**

Apparently I had to specify `.Include` statements because lazy loading was disabled and `x.Class1`, `x.Class2` and `x.Class3` always had the `null` value. I feel ashamed because I didn't explicitly state that lazy loading was disabled - the problem would have been obvious then.

However thanks to Ladislav's post, I improved my code like so:

```
Database DB = new Database(); // object context

int SomeNumber = 1; // some number
List<SomeClass> retValue = DB.SomeClass
    .Include("Class1")
    .Include("Class2")
    .Include("Class3")
    .Where(x =>
        SomeNumber == x.Class1.SomeNumber ||
        SomeNumber == x.Class2.SomeNumber ||
        SomeNumber == x.Class3.SomeNumber)
    .ToList();
```

I didn't know LINQ-to-Entities should perform automatic null coalescing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IMHO you should be OK with just this:

```
Database DB = new Database(); 
var result = DB.SomeClass.Where(x =>
                            Number == x.Class1.SomeNumber ||
                            Number == x.Class2.SomeNumber ||
                            Number == x.Class3.SomeNumber)
                         .ToList();
```

Your query loads all data and after that you evaluate condition in .NET = you must test null value prior to accessing `SomeNumber` but that is not needed if you evaluate `SomeNumber` in SQL through Linq-to-entities. Linq-to-entities should perform automatic null coalescing.

Comment: Actually the solution was (I usually find it myself shortly after I ask) that due to lazy loading disabled, I had to do `var result = DB.SomeClass.Include("Class1").Include("Class2").Include("Class3")` prior to running `Where` clause. However I am marking this as accepted because you taught me how to improve my code (use `Where` in LINQ-To-Entities directly)

Answer (score 3):

According to your logic, if x.Class1 is not null, but x.Class1.SomeNumber is 3, it won't check all the other clauses.

If you want to check, if just some `ClassN.SomeNumber == SomeNumber`, then you should do it like this:

```
int SomeNumber = 1; // some number 
List<SomeClass> retValue = result 
    .Where(x => 
        { 
            if (x.Class1 != null && x.Class1.SomeNumber == SomeNumber) 
                return true;
            else if (x.Class2 != null && x.Class2.SomeNumber == SomeNumber) 
                return true;
            else if (x.Class3 != null && x.Class3.SomeNumber == SomeNumber) 
                return true;
            return false;
        }) 
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Isn't this code the same as the one I used, except my code has got 1 more line?

Comment: No, since it returns immediately if the numbers are equal. In your code it's possible, that there is a right number, but it gets overriden by another if clause.

Comment: It can't get overridden because there are `else` clauses, and would return 0 if none of the conditions match.